# Is riak erlang client pool needed?

Tags: erlang, connection, pool, riak

I am using riak-erlang-client to connect with riak server. And for each request, I have to start_link first. My question is "Is riak client pool needed in production?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is generally a good idea to use a connection pool. We use [poolboy](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy) inside Riak CS, others have used [pooler](https://github.com/seth/pooler).